# How can i make if in my webkit webview click on Amazon link or facebook link it will open app or if not found it will open in browser

Tags: ios, swift

here is my webview controller

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class NewsWeb: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let url = "https://google.com"
        let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)
        self.webView.load(request)
        webView.scrollView.addSubview(refreshControl)
        webView.navigationDelegate = self as? WKNavigationDelegate
        webView.uiDelegate = self as? WKUIDelegate
        webView.scrollView.delegate = self as? UIScrollViewDelegate
        webView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        webView.isMultipleTouchEnabled = false
    }
```

how can make if in the webview page clik on Amazon or Facbook link it will be open in app if in the device has installed the app if not found the app it will be open in browser

Comment: https://kitefaster.com/2016/07/13/how-to-open-ios-app-with-custom-url/

Answer (score 1):

You could use my code and modify on you own bases:

```
func makeSocialLinkViewModel(for socialNetwork: SocialNetwork) -> TextCellViewModel {
     TextCellViewModel(text: socialNetwork.rawValue) {
        UIApplication.tryOpening(urls: [socialNetwork.appUrl, socialNetwork.websiteUrl])
    }
}
```

I have a let:

```
let facebook = makeSocialLinkViewModel(for: .facebook)
```

case:

```
case facebook = "Facebook"
var appUrl: String {
        case .facebook:
            return Constants.Facebook.appUrl
        }

    var websiteUrl: String {
        switch self {
        case .facebook:
            return Constants.Facebook.websiteUrl
        }
    }
```

And finally constants are just like:

```
struct Facebook {
    static let appUrl = "fb://profile/(your_facebook_id)"
    static let websiteUrl = "https://www.facebook.com/(your_url)"
}
```

Hope this helps